# MySQL DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE fails to update due to a NOT NULL field which is already set

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL DB which is using strict mode so I need to fill all NOT NULL values when I insert a row. The API Im creating is using just DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE functionality to do both inserts/updates.

The client application complains if any NOT NULL attributes are inserted which is expected.

Basic example (id is primary key and theare are two fields that are NOT NULL aaa and xxx)

```
INSERT INTO tablename (aaa, xxx, id ) VALUES ( "value", "value", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE aaa=VALUES(aaa), xxx=VALUES(xxx)
```

All good so far. Once it is inserted, the system would allow doing updates. Nevertheless, I get the following error when updating only one of the fields.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (aaa, id ) VALUES ( "newValue", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE aaa=VALUES(aaa)

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value
```

This Exception is a lie as the row is already inserted and xxx attribute has "value" as value. I would expect the following sentence to be equivalent to:

```
UPDATE tablename SET aaa="newValue" WHERE id=1
```

I would be glad if someone can shed some light about this issue.

Edit:

I can use the SQL query in PhpMyAdmin successfully to update just one field so I am afraid that this is not a SQL problem but a driver problem with JDBC. That may not have solution then.

@Marc B: Your insight is probably true and would indicate what I just described. That would mean that there is a bug in JDBC as it should not do that check when the insert is of ON DUPLICATE type as there may be a default value for the row after all. Can't provide real table data but I believe that all explained above is quite clear.

@ruakh: It does not fail to insert, neither I am expecting delayed validation. One requirement I have is to have both insert/updates done using the same query as the servlet does not know if the row exists or not. The JAVA API service only fails to update a row that has NOT NULL fields which were already filled when the insert was done. The exception is a lie because the field DOES have a default value as it was inserted before the update.

Comment: show us the `create table tablename` output, so we can see the exact structure of the table. if mysql is saying that the field doesn't have a default value, then it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: Why would you write an `INSERT` statement that you know can never successfully insert a record? Why would you expect MySQL to delay validation of the `INSERT` statement until after it's determined whether it violates a primary-key constraint? Why do you say "this Exception is a lie" when the exception's only claim, `Field 'xxx' doesn't have a default value`, is perfectly correct?

Comment: because the update doesn't occur until AFTER a unique key violation occurs. and that doesn't happen until the insert is succesfully attempted. yours doesn't get that far, because the sql parser sees you've not provided an `xxx` field in your insert. it doesn't get far enough to see that it'll be a on dupe/insert situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of DRY / SRP fail; in an attempt to not duplicate code you've created a function that violates the single responsibility principle.

The semantics of an `INSERT` statement is that you expect no conflicting rows; the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option is merely there to avoid handling the conflict inside your code, requiring another separate query. This is quite different from an `UPDATE` statement, where you would expect at least one matching row to be present.

Imagine that MySQL would only check the columns when an `INSERT` doesn't conflict and for some reason a row was just removed from the database and your code that expects to perform an update has to deal with an exception it doesn't expect. Given the difference in statement behaviour it's good practice to separate your insert and update logic.

Theory aside, MySQL puts together an execution plan when a query is run; in the case of an `INSERT` statement it has to assume that it might succeed when attempted, because that's the most optimal strategy. It prevents having to check indices etc. only to find out later that a column is missing.

This is per design and not a bug in JDBC.

Comment: I tend to be fanatic with the SRP but it is not the case if I can't afford to query the service to find out if there is actually a row. So then, it makes sense that I apply an INSERT ON DUPLICATE to perform both which is ALLOWED by MySQL straight using command line but not through JDBC. So it may not be a bug, but I think they should allow this if programmer chooses so.

Comment: @Capagris If you can't afford it, and the code context doesn't give you any clue, you should add all columns lest the data integrity might be affected; btw, can't you just disable strict mode :)

Comment: @Capagris Btw, you can keep track of the affected rows after an update to check whether the row is likely to be missing.